# Which controller and action are being accessed with Rails, Devise, and Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth

I'm using Devise and Omniauth in my Rails 4 application. In my view I have a button to "Login With Facebook" that directs the user to `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)`. This works as expected and sends the user to `/users/auth/facebook`. Then, that URL appears to be correctly redirecting the user to the Facebook login page.

How can I determine which controller/action are being used for this redirect? I would like to set a `return_url` before redirecting to Facebook. I was able to do this in my regular `Session` and `Registration` controllers by subclassing the Devise version and adding my code, like this:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def new
    return_url = params[:return_url]
    store_location_for(:user, return_url) unless return_url.nil?
    super
  end
end
```

Then, I tell devise to use my new controllers:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
```

I'm trying to accomplish the same sort of thing with the omniauth functionality? Is there some way to find out which controller is being accessed when the user visits `/users/auth/facebook`? If so, can I subclass it and add functionality in the same way I did above?

**UPDATE**

I found the controller/action by running 'rake routes'. Here's what it says:

```
user_omniauth_authorize    GET|POST    /users/auth/:provider(.:format)     users/omniauth_callbacks#passthru {:provider=>/facebook/}
```

So I was able to find the `passthru` method that is being used, but that has left me even more confused. It's in `Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController` and says:

```
def passthru
  render status: 404, text: "Not found. Authentication passthru."
end
```

I'm confused how this method is resulting in the user being redirected to Facebook.

Comment: Have a look at [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) you need to add a callback_url :)

Comment: I don't think that's what I'm looking for. The callback_url is the url that processes the request when the user is sent back from Facebook. That's set globally for the application. I'm looking to set a redirect_url before the user is sent to Facebook, and then ensure that the callback_url ultimately redirects the user to that URL that was set.

Comment: Well that's sad because I got the same issue and you actually never found the "why" of your question (it's not going through your controller), just got a way around. I'm still searching.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can pass parameters to the `user_omniauth_authorize_path`, and then retrieve them in the callback URL using `request.env["omniauth.params"]`. So, I changed my link to: `user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook, { return_url: '/test_redirect_path' }`

Then in my OmniauthCallbacksController I added:

`store_location_for(:user, request.env["omniauth.params"]["return_url"])`
before the call to `sign_in_and_redirect @user`.

This seems to have done the trick.